# When to create a new time-series database?

Tags: influxdb

I am a new user of the time-series database (TSDB) [InfluxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/) 1.7 (and a new user to databases in general).

Since I just started with InfluxDB, my question are linked to the architechrue I need. And there is a lot of information out there about how to store the data inside the database and such best practices ([example](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/)).

**Question**: However, since I can create multiple DBs, is there a general rule of thumb applicable to TSDBs or InfluxDB in particular, on when do I need to create a new DB? More importantly, how to be able to measure when a new DB is needed and one does not suffice?

One thing I know for sure is that the [Retention Policy](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/database_management/#retention-policy-management) is set per DB, so based on that is a good reason to separate DBs. Are there any other things to consider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be a minimalist and use a single instance of time series database unless you hit a compelling reason to create an additional instance.

A small correction, you can create multiple retention policies within an InfluxDB instance. You can even insert data into a same measurement using different retention policies.